# how to read a function type in english

Tags: f#

```
let compose f g = fun x -> f (g x)
let mal2 x = 2 * x
let plus1 x = x + 1
let mal2Plus1 = compose plus1 mal2

val compose : ('b -> 'c) -> ('a -> 'b) -> ('a -> 'c)
```

Can anybody teach me how to read the function type of compose

Answer (score 7):

There are multiple ways to read the function type depending on how you use it. But if you use it in the way demonstrated in your example (`compose plus1 mal2`) then the following reading makes sense:

`compose` is a function that:

- takes an argument `'b -> 'c` which is itself a function that knows how to turn a value of type `'b` into a different value of type `'c`
- takes another argument `'a -> 'b` which is (again) a function that can transforrm values `'a` into values of type `'b`.

given these two functions, it is possible to run them in sequence - if you have a value `'a` you can apply the second function to get a value of type `'b` and this value can be passed to the first function to get `'c`. This is exactly what `compose` does so:

- the result is a composed function that takes `'a` and produces `'c` (which can only be done by applying the second function to `'a` and then applying the first function to the result)

Answer (score 3):

Tomas' answer is absolutely correct, but it does not cover *currying*.

For better understanding of what is a curried function, look at `compose` function and forget for a moment that its arguments are, in turn, functions.

Let's call them `'x`, `'y`, and `'z` to avoid confusion with `'a`, `'b`, and `'c` from the original code:

```
val compose: 'x -> 'y -> 'z
```

In imperative world, you will see something like this:

```
z compose(x theX, y theY);
```

It's a function of **two** arguments, `x` and `y`, which returns a value of `z`.

In a functional world, `val compose: 'x -> 'y -> 'z` may be considered in two essentially different manners:

1. A function of **two** arguments `'x` and `'y`, returning `'z`
2. A function of **one** argument `'x`, returning a *function* that, in turn, will take **one** argument of `'y` and return `'z`.

This process is called *partial application*.

Returning back to your original `val compose : ('b -> 'c) -> ('a -> 'b) -> ('a -> 'c)`, it can be read two ways:

1. Exactly as Tomas described: a function that

   - Takes **two** arguments, `('b -> 'c)` and  `('a -> 'b)`, correspondingly;
   - Returns a function of type `('a -> 'c)`
2. Or, alternatively, a function that

   - Takes **one** argument `('b -> 'c)`
   - Returns a function that

     - Takes **one** argument `('a -> 'b)`
     - Returns a function of type `('a -> 'c)`

Comment: +1 This is great addition to what I said. I think there is actually third reading (which is quite interesting) when `compose` takes three arguments (and you can write `compose plus1 mul2 5`).